# read string in mysql and file like msword (search form)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a task where I need to upload about 50 msword document in mysql database, it is not a problem. But in the "admin" how can I develop a script where it can find the string in the database and it also can find the string in the file like msword?

For example, I find the word "programming" in the search box, and the word is only in the file "msword"!

So the main problem is how to develop search script that can read data in mysql and in the file like msword?

I am currently using "wordpress" with "contact form 7" to develop upload form.

Can someone give me some suggestions.

Comment: You're storing the .doc/.docx files in a BLOB field in the database? You will **NOT** be able to look for words in those records with either fulltext or standard `like '%...%'` searches. .doc files are compound OLE documents, .docx is a zip file - either way they're essentially binary garbage as far as MySQL is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

You should not only save the Word files as binary files (which are not searchable by MySQL) but should also extract the text within the Word files and save it as a TEXT in the DB. Then you could search with wildcards (i.e. `'WHERE text LIKE "%searchterm%"'`) and find the words in the files.

Note however that this will become very slow with more and larger files!

Comment: Do you have any script for extract the text within the Word files and save it as a TEXT in the DB?

Comment: ok..now i found the solutions , just install google custom search, when you want find string in pdf or word files use google custom search..superb work like charm.. :)

Comment: Sure, but that gives Google access to the documents, which might not be what you want. If you want control over your data and search algorithm, do as in my answer!